# Portuguese charset problem

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, character-encoding

I’m a headache with the damn charset.

Portuguese charset=iso-8859-1

On my HTML I have:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

On my config.php:

```
$config['charset'] = 'ISO-8859-1';
```

I have the word `‘café’, coffee.`

It is been displayed like: `cafŽ.`

Any ideas?!

Thanks in advance for any help

**Edit

I don't know if it matters but I'm using Eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the encoding of the file in Eclipse set to? Right-Klick on the file in Eclipse, check under "Properties". It must be the same as in your meta-tag.

Answer (score 2):

thanks so much, i believe your answer is the best one:

```
$string = 'café'; 
utf8_decode($string);
```

OR

```
$string = 'café'; 
utf8_encode($string);
```

with meta charset in the header of each file, the issue of portugues characters will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you switch to UTF-8?

**edit** You might also want to switch to using entities.

`&eacute;` would be the é

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Comment: Now its is displaying a ? instead of é (caf�)

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the default charset in the browser first, it could be set to ISO-8859-15 or UTF8. I have had the reverse problem of my browser encoding was set to ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF8.

Secondly is this data static or coming from a database? If it is from mySQL for example, check the collation of the database, is it in latin1 or utf8? 
If coming from a UTF8 collated database (or not - as you're using PHP) you can try

```
$string = 'café';
utf8_decode($string);
```

OR

```
$string = 'café';
utf8_encode($string);
```

Moving to UTF8 may be a good idea because functions like PHPs utf8_encode() and utf8_decode() but if it's not appropriate to your market then that is that.

If the utf8_encode or utf8_decode functions work, you should look at your input method and input encoding as you will likely find a problem there.

P.S. I have the same problems from time to time being in Brazil... I feel your pain mate!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one here:

```
$string = 'café';
htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
```

Take care!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the resource bundle  in the  project explorer and then right click on that file and change char set to utf=8 and then save the settings.