# MySql database doesen't correctly store data when using unusual letters/symbols

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a simple form that sends (via php) some variables to a mySql database.

The problem is that it's focused to Portuguese audience, and we use several unusual letters, like "ç" and "ã". Whenever someone sends data with those letters, the result is very "garbled" in the phpMyAdmin.

Quick example for a field would be "Escola de Condução Clássica" apears as "4573636f6c6120646520636f6e6475c383c2a7c383c2a36f20436c617373696361" in the phpMyAdmin.

I tried setting the collation to "utf8_bin", with no avail.

Any ideias?

Thank you.

EDIT: Field type is varchar(30) and charset shows as "utf8".

Comment: 1) you didn't tell us what the **type** of the field you store data to is, 2) phpMyAdmin is the worst type of "software" you can have for managing MySQL, 3) utf8_bin is the **collation** which are the rules for ordering the letters, it's not the charset being used (which should be utf8, use `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` and check what the charset being used is).

Comment: This can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305947/portuguese-charset-problem

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific. I'll update the question.

Comment: If the field is a varchar and charset is utf8, you need to instruct the browser to display characters using utf8. Use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>` in the `<HEAD>` section of your HTML page and echo out the content. Don't use PhpMyAdmin for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. Turns out I just needed to call my hosting to change the php setting. I wish I had tried this beforehand, but I though it was something wrong on my end. Also, it makes no sense for them to have another encoding other than UTF-8, considering its a Portugal (european) based hosting.

Anyway, if someone gets this error, try asking the hosting about which encoding is used in the php setting (it should have been UTF-8 in my case, might be diferent for you).

And yes, this problem took a while because I eventually ignored it, but I had to do something similar recently in a diferent site (using the same hosting).

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE `mytable` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8

Comment: Although that worked to decode the fields, the unusual letters still aren't yet decoded. I now have the same field in the example as "Escola de conduÃ§Ã£o Classica". As you see, the "condução" became a "conduÃ§Ã£o".

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if that's your browser. I agree about not using phpAdmin as a "viewing tool". However, what happens with ALTER TABLE `mytable` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1 ?

Comment: Shows the same, no change.

Comment: "Shows the same" - **where**? What are you using to check the output and *how* are you using it? Still using PhpMyAdmin? You think it has the correct charset set in the HTML?

Comment: @Marco - are you able to NOT use phpMyAdmin to retrieve your data? It seems that your data is being stored as intended; only the display tool/path is mangling your perception. phpMyAdmin has many variants, but the config file does determine how  IT interprets data, then you have the connection properties (SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS =latin1;) and then you have the browser options. With some other tool, like a PHP connection/console session, you might be able to take away the distracting factors.