# PHP HTML encoding

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I'm trying to parse a HTML page, but the encoding is messing my results. After some research I found a very popular solution using `utf8_encode()` and `utf8_decode()`, but it doesn't change anything. In the following lines, you can check my code and the output.

### Code

```
$str_html = $this->curlHelper->file_get_contents_curl($page);
$str_html = utf8_encode($str_html);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->resolveExternals = true;
$dom->substituteEntities = false;
@$dom->loadHTML($str_html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);

(...)
$profile = array();
for ($index = 0; $index < $table_lines->length; $index++) {
    $desc = utf8_decode($table_lines->item($index)->firstChild->nodeValue);
}
```

### Output

```
Testar Ã© bom
```

**Should be**

```
Testar é bom
```

### What I've tried

- htmlentities():

  `htmlentities($table_lines->item($index)->lastChild->nodeValue, ENT_NOQUOTES, ini_get('ISO-8859-1'), false);`
- htmlspecialchars():

  `htmlspecialchars($table_lines->item($index)->lastChild->nodeValue, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'ISO-   8859-1', false);`
- Change my file's charset as decribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6306027/1488993).

### Some more information

- Website encoding: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refer this link as it would give you more options to handle such characters
http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following without a prior `utf8_decode()`:

```php
mb_convert_encoding($str, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
```

Alternatively, don't use `utf8_decode()` and try to change your website meta to:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

---

- [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Just to understand... since my HTML is `ISO-8859-1`, why is it passed as `$to_encoding` and `UTF-8` as `$from_encoding`?

Comment: @Doon Because the string you're trying to print is in `UTF-8` encoding but needs to be in `ISO-8859-1` encoding to be properly printed on your `ISO-8859-1` encoded website. So naturally, you need to convert from `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-1` encoding.