# PHP HTML encoding strange behavior

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

Some time ago I asked [how to properly convert HTML encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335092/php-html-encoding) and I had an answer. I'm using this answer since that, but today I noticed a strange behavior of the `mb_convert_encoding`. Depending on the place where you are running, it outputs differently:

```
Browser (Tested in Chrome and Firefox):
W/o mb: 42Â sp
mb: 42 sp

PHP CLI:
W/o mb: 31 sp
mb: 31�sp
```

Using the browser, the `mb_convert_encoding` outputs correctly but, on the other hand, using the command line, without `mb_convert_encoding` is the right output. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

### The code

```
$str_html = $this->curlHelper->file_get_contents_curl($page);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->resolveExternals = true;
$dom->substituteEntities = false;
@$dom->loadHTML($str_html);

$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);

(...)

foreach ($table_lines as $line) {
    $tds = $line->childNodes;

    $sp = mb_convert_encoding($tds->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');

    echo "W/o mb: " . $tds->item(0)->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
    echo "mb: " . $sp . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: did u try utf8_decode ?

Comment: @Vishnu Nope, but I just did. It outputs like the mb, in both cases.

Comment: Start reading here: http://kunststube.net/encoding

Comment: Hi @deceze, congratulations it's an awesome article. Let's see if I understood after reading your article. The website is `ISO-8859-1` and, when I call `file_get_contents_post`, the result is `UTF-8`. So, I correctly call `mb_convert_encoding` to interpret it as `ISO-8859-1`. That said, I assume that the browser interprets correctly the `ISO-8859-1` string but the CLI doesn't (it interprets as UTF-8). Right?