# show Portuguese word in confirm dialogue box in php

Tags: php

I have a string and i want to show that string in confirm dialogue box.Here is my code:

```
function check_date(today,date_expire)
  {

    $val=htmlentities('Você tem certeza que deseja cancelar esta compra?');

    var r=confirm("<?php echo $val;?>");
    if (r==true)
    { 
     alert(ok);
    }
}
```

but it gives me output like:

> Voc&e circ; tem certeza que deseja cancelar esta compra?

Can you please tell me the proper code so that i can show:

> Você tem certeza que deseja cancelar esta compra?

in confirm dialogue box?? Thanks!!

Comment: this is because your function `htmlentities` it transforms it to this..

Comment: i am very sorry.actually first time i put the equivalent html code there.but it automatically translates to Portuguese.Thats why it looks same as input.Now i m giving a li'l speace so that you can uderstand my problem.

Comment: if characters are displayed wrong, you dont have to use htmlentities to get them right. try to set the charset to the right one

Comment: but i had also tried this without this function htmlentities();it gave me the same output.

Comment: because you have a diffrent charset. see this post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305947/portuguese-charset-problem

Comment: The obsession on htmlentities is likely irrelevant (see the documentation at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php ).  You'll want to make sure the encoding is right on htmlentities and it's not needed here, but UTF-8 throughout your entire system is the actual problem.  The PHP script, the Javascript, the HTML ... all must be UTF-8 encoded.  Most stuff still uses Microsoft crap encoding as though it's the only encoding on the planet, so you have to set it to use UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are having an enconding issue. Not sure how exactly though, but `htmlentities()` isn't the answer. **JavaScript does not recognize or format HTML in message boxes.**

If your website is using UTF-8 encoding, just make sure the .php file is also encoded the same way. It should do the trick.

```
var r = confirm('Você tem certeza que deseja cancelar esta compra?');
```

As last resource, try this:

```
var r = confirm(<?php echo json_encode('Você tem certeza que deseja cancelar esta compra?'); ?>);
```

Comment: It works in windows xp smoothly but it is not working in linux.giving me null in alert.