# I am having a javascript portuguese special character validation error

Tags: javascript

This application is to teach Portuguese to children. But i am having trouble as it enters all the english character successfully but when accented character comes i get an error

```
<div class="ui segment segment-container">
    <div class="label-container">
        <label id="label" class="word"></label>
    </div><br />
    <div class="ui input">
        <input id="key" type="text" placeholder="Type here">
    </div><br />
    <div class="icon-container correct"> You got it right! <i class="check icon"></i></div>
    <div class="icon-container wrong">Oops! This seems wrong <i class="x icon"></i></div>
    <div class="icon-container success">Success <i class="thumbs up outline icon"></i></div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.correct').hide();
        $('.wrong').hide();
        $('.success').hide();
        $('#key').hover();
        var randomKey = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6))
        var labels = ["the pencil is red", "the car is blue", "the sky is blue", "the grass is green", "he has a red clock", "i have a yellow box"];
        $('#label').html(labels[randomKey]).toString().toLowerCase();
        var label = $('#label').html().toString().toLowerCase();
        var counter = 0;

        $("#key").keyup(function (e) {
            var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
            var enteredLetter = String.fromCharCode(code).toLowerCase().toString();
            if (code !== 8 && code !== 46 && code !== 13 && code !==16) {
                if (label[counter] === enteredLetter) {
                    $('.correct').fadeIn();
                    $('.wrong').hide();
                    $('.success').hide();
                    ++counter;
                    if (counter === label.length) {
                        counter = 0;
                        $('.correct').hide();
                        $('.wrong').hide();
                        $('#key').val('');
                        $('.success').fadeIn();
                        randomKey = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6));
                        $('#label').html(labels[randomKey]).toString().toLowerCase();
                        label = $('#label').html().toString().toLowerCase();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $('.correct').hide();
                    $('.wrong').fadeIn();
                    $('.success').hide();
                    var dataEntered = $('#key').val().toString();
                    $('#key').val(dataEntered.slice(0, -1));
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

the entered letter is taking character one by one and checking it. but when a accented character is types (two keys are pressed) it says it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the header of your html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

and be sure to save the html with ut8 encoding as well.

Maybe this will solve the problem, as it had done for this question: [Portuguese charset problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305947/portuguese-charset-problem).

Comment: This should do it: 
`var objRegExp  = /^[a-z\u00C0-\u00ff]+$/;
        if (objRegExp.test(input)) {
            //do your letter checking routine here:
        }`